# Bootstrap relative path navigation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a django project with bootstrap3 navigation. In the main template I have the following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">branding goes here</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="about">About</a>
                </li>
```

The first time the project loads in my dev environment and I click on 'About' it works fine using the defined route:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/
```

However if I click on it again , I get

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/about/
```

which obviously is incorrect. What is the best way to avoid this 'relative routing' error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a absolute path instead of a relative one.

```
<a href="/about">About</a>
```

That way the browser will not append your `href` attribute to the actual `window.location.href` value to create the complete URL. [Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160221033509/http://jeffreybarke.net/2013/06/paths-and-urls-relative-and-absolute/) is a little resource you can read about absolute and relative paths.

BTW, this has nothing to to with Python or Django.

Answer (score 3):

Add a leading slash to the href:

`<a href="/about">About</a>`